# reimplimenting a VB6 nested type as a structure in VB.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, vb6, structure

i am porting a VB6 app that uses a complex type to contain a structured message system. the current problem I am working thru is converting this to a VB.net structure. Here is the declaration:

```
Global Const MAX_MSGS = 150     ' Max number of messages per set
Global Const MAX_SETS = 100     ' Max number of message sets
Global Const MAX_HGI = 96       ' Max number of HowGozIt messages per set
Global Const MAX_WPS = 96       ' Max number of way points per message set
Global Const MAX_FLS = 15       ' Max number of flight levels per waypoint

Type MessageRec
 MessType As Integer           'Message Type
 MessIndex As Integer          'Message Index (not used currently)
 MessNextBit As Integer        'last bit for Mops messages
 MessTotal As Integer          'Mess total
 MultMessBit As Integer        'Multiple message bit position
 MessTitle As String * 25      'Message title
 MessNo As String              'Message Numbers and data for mops edit
 MessText As String            'I/F displayable text
 MessStr As String             'message bits for mops msgs, can be file for acars,aoc
 MessLabel As String * 4       'Label and sublabel
 TimeDelay As Integer          'Delayed time in seconds before message is delivered
 Active As Boolean             'Flag determines active/deactive
 AutoInit As Boolean            'Flag if part of auto init bundle
 AIDelay As Integer             'Auto Init time delay (secs)
End Type

Type WayPointRec
 Name As String * 7
 DeltaTime As String * 5
 FltLevel As String * 5
 DeltaFuel As String * 5
 Lat As String * 6                   ' Latitude of waypoint
 Long As String * 7                  ' Longitude of waypoint
 SAT As String * 3                   ' Standard Air temp (no need to save in database)
 Via As String
 NumAlts As String * 2                ' Numer of altitudes for following weather data
 FL(0 To MAX_FLS) As String * 3      ' Flight level for this weather
 WindDir(0 To MAX_FLS) As String * 3 ' Wind direction
 WindSpd(0 To MAX_FLS) As String * 3 ' Wind speed
 Temp(0 To MAX_FLS) As String * 3    ' Temperature
End Type

Type MessageStore                  
 Nmsgs As Integer              'Number of messages in the message set
 Fltno As Integer              'Flight Number
 SubFltNo As String * 1        'For multiple messages with same flight number
 CityPair As String * 7        'City Pair
 Descr As String * 12          'Message Set Description
 Hot As Integer                'Hot/Cold flag (true => hot, use second weather message set)
 DWndFL(0 To 3) As Integer     'Descent wind flight level (4 altitudes)
 DWndDir(0 To 3) As Integer    'Descent wind direction (4 altitudes)
 DWndSpd(0 To 3) As Integer    'Descent wind speed (4 altitudes)
 WndSpd(0 To 9) As Integer     'Start/end wind speed (5 altitudes)
 WndDir(0 To 9) As Integer     'Start/end wind direction (5 altitudes)
 TempDev(0 To 1) As Integer    'Start/end Temperature deviation from standard
 altn(0 To 1) As String * 3    'Alternate airports for area weather information
 nHGIwpts As Integer           'Number of waypoints for howgozit info
 HGIinfo(1 To MAX_HGI, 0 To 3) As String * 5  'Howgozit information
 MsgData(1 To MAX_MSGS) As MessageRec 'Message data mlw 7/12/02 changed 30 to 60
 nwpts As Integer              'Number of waypoints for winds/temp info
 WayPoints(1 To MAX_WPS) As WayPointRec 'For canned messages
 Index As Integer
 Active As Boolean             'Flag determines active/deactive
 DeltaArrivalTime As Integer   'add or subtract to get actual arrival time
 TimeToGate As Integer         'Time to gate from T/D for HOWGOZIT
End Type
```

the structure MessageStore  is the on disk format (all fields convert to strings for writing) which is read by another C program.

I have no problem converting to fixed length stings for the simple strings but converting the arrays of fixed length strings in WayPointRec which in then included in the WayPoints array of WayPointRec's in MessageStore is where I am currently stuck

also how to best handle the "HGIinfo" 2D string array of fixed length strings

edit

left out one more detail - top level

```
Public MsgArray() As MessageStore
```

where MsgArray grown as

```
redim preserve MsgArray(x)
```

with x limited  0-100

Comment: is there any flexibility with the C program consuming the data, or is it basically a 3rd party affair?  This is not to open the door to a "just do it all in Net" response, but some of those things are very problematic.

Comment: C program runs cross platform, VAX-VMS, AIX 4.2 , SYSTEM V R4 unix , Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Class MessageStore
    Public MsgData As MessageRec
    Public WayPoints As WayPointRec
    Public DWndFL(3) As Integer
    Public HGIinfo(MAX_HGI, 3)() As String
End Class

Public Class WayPointRec
    Public FL(MAX_FLS)() As String
End Class
```

however, it's probably best to rework the arrays to something like this (or alternatively, turn them all into classes but that's too much work):

```
Private _HGIinfo(MAX_HGI, 3, 5) As String
```

furthermore, don't use Structures, you won't be able to init sizes of arrays, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2hkbth2a%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx#BKMK_CreatingAnArray

that should cover the conversions, need to extrapolate to rest.

***3 issues:***

- cannot init an array of arrays in .net with a bounds specifier. ie:
  Public HGIinfo(MAX_HGI,3)(5) As String
- cannot init sizes of arrays using Structures
- cannot init array bounds (1 to #), arrays start from 0 in vb.net.

you can solve them by using getter/setter properties (but that would be ugly):

```
Private _HGIinfo(MAX_HGI, 3)() As String
Public Property HGIinfo(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer) As String()
    Get
        ' perform some checks on value or MAX_HGI
        Return _HGIinfo(a, b)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String())
        ' perform some checks on value or MAX_HGI
        _HGIinfo(a, b) = value
    End Set
End Property
HGIinfo(0, 1)(3).SubString(0, 4) ' would get the first 4 chars of the 3rd string, at position 0,1 in the _HGIinfo array
```

also, to initialize the String() arrays with an upper bounds, you'd need something like:

```
Private _HGIinfoStr(5) As String
Private _HGIinfo(MAX_HGI, 3)() As String
Public Sub New()
    _HGIinfo(0, 0) = _HGIinfoStr ' would need to loop through 0 to MAX_HGI, and also 0-3 to init all the members of the _HGIinfo array with bounds.
End Sub
```

again, that would be really messy. class method for reference:

```
Public Class HGIinfoClass
    Public _HGIinfoStr(5) As String
End Class
Private _HGIinfo(MAX_HGI, 3) As HGIinfoClass
Public Sub test()
    _HGIinfo(3, 3)._HGIinfoStr(3) = "test"
End Sub
```

in fact, i was thinking of a way to use properties to maintain the current function and reformat for the new array bounds and return, unfortunately, it's not that simple. would requires array copies, or some elaborate loops.

edit: also, another alternative would be to turn them into Classes that inherit from ArrayList, and set the Capacity property. but that's less efficient overall.

and it is also possible to specify lower bound of an array using:

```
Array.CreateInstance(GetType(String), New Integer(){5}, New Integer(){1}).
```

see (again, really ugly): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/x836773a

Comment: see edit at end of question. MsgArray is a dynamic array of MsgStores limited to a max size of 100 MsgStores

Comment: you can either do it the same way in vb.net or use an `ArrayList`, which implements the `iList` interface: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.collections.arraylist